# PHP header() usage and why it isn't redirecting

Tags: php

I am trying to do a simple logout page where it destroys the user session and then redirects them to the home page.... not sure why this isn't working.  Here is the whole file.

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header('location: http://example.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ob_start();** on top of page..
and **ob_clean();** on bottom of page.. then this work fine..

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will works for you :

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `?> <?php` statement in your code

A simple soloution is Adding `ob_start();` at the top of your code
and `ob_end();` at bottom